# How to stop counting at specific page and block last page, then start again in roman style

Tags: appendices

First of all, my english is not awesome (as you can see) I apology about that.

I'm writing my bachelor thesis using Latex (texmaker)

Everything is fine except that my school want some specifics things .

I will try to explain with a graphic:

[image: The way I have to count]
I would like to have in the table of content all of chapter, table of figure, some document extern until table of appendix.
At table of appendix I would like that number of page stop counting
And than, I would like to start a new counter of page from I to ... to count the appendix.
And finally after the last appendix, stop again counter

and have just an abstract (plainstyle) that doesn't count in the total page.

Hope you understood what I'm looking for.
In case, just let me know.

Thanks you so much for all your help I'm getting a bit crazy

Best regards
Simon

Comment: You want something like `\pagestyle{empty}` for the for first things like `title page` etc., then `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for the chapters and Table of appendix and then `\pagenumbering{Roman}` for the appendix itself. Finally `\pagestyle{empty}` again

Comment: Hey christian, thanks for your answer. My problem is, on the header. If i write \appendix  and than \pagenumbering{roman}, Yes My appendix start at I,II,III, but on header of  the rest (chapter 2-3-etc..) I have page 8 on XVI.  The command lastpage take the roman style unfortunately.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Try putting a `\label` before `\appendix` and use `\pageref` to get the number of the last arabic numbered page.

Comment: Hey Mike, I did, and tried  and added to the fancyhead, but doesn't work. In fact, it's strange, I do have on my text page 1 of 8  etc... till page 8 of 8 and than page 9 of 8 , 14 of 8  etc... And than I have my appendix that start with new page numbering. I don't know how to have 2 different "lastpage" . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have an answer. You have to put the `\label` before `\appendix`, but `\pagenumbering{roman}` after the first `\chapter` in the appendix.

This should do what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage{} sur \pageref*{pba}} 

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some Text}
Page before appendix: \pageref{pba}

\lipsum[1-20]

\label{pba}

\appendix
% don't put \pagestyle{headings} and/or \pagenumbering{roman} here!
\chapter{Stuff}
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey Mike, Absolutely awesome. Thanks you so much, it works. Was becoming crazy. I added the   also had to add \fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage{} of \pageref*{pbb}}         and \label{pbb} at the end of my appendix. Thanks you so much. Now will have to find a way to create a Table of appendix

Comment: @SimonSays: for the table of appendix the `minitoc` package may be of help. But since I never used it, I can't tell if it offers what you need.